# Plurals, if statement python

Tags: python, eclipse

So many questions.. At the moment my code is calculating the cost, number of adults and children. If the user only inputs 1 child I want it to print child, not children.

```
serviceType = input("Would you like (M)edium or (R)are steak?")
if serviceType == "r":
    rare = float((noChild * rare) * DISCOUNT) + (noAdult * BASIC)
    print("That is " + formatCurrency(rare) + " for rare choice for " + str(noAdult) + " adults and " + str(noChild) + " children. Enjoy!")
```

The output shows 
This is $-- for rare choice for 2 adults and 1 children. 
I need it to say "This is $-- for rare choice for 1 adults and 1 child.

I figure I would need to put an

```
if noChild == 1
```

statement somewhere, but not sure where to add it in?

I also have the same format of code to calculate "medium" so I can't change the sentence to child, otherwise if the user enters 2 it will be 2 child. I hope I have explained myself properly?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to depluralize "children" but not "adults"? :)

Comment: I want to do both.. but I thought if I can do it for the child, then I can use the same method for adults. Essentially, I want it to print children/ child, adults, adult, depending on the number. So if ==1 then child and adult . @BlueIce

Comment: That makes sense, and I applaud your work ethic. Keep up the good work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the print statement like this:

```
print("That is " + formatCurrency(rare) + " for rare choice for " + str(noAdult) +
     (" adult" if noAdult==1 else " adults") + " and " + str(noChild) +
     (" child" if noChild==1 else " children") + ". Enjoy!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x if ... else y` construction:

```
def children_str(number):
    return "{} {}".format(number, 'child' if number == 1 else 'children')

for i in range(3):
    print children_str(i)
```

Output:

```
0 children
1 child
2 children
```

you can generalize this function:

```
def pl(number, singular, plural=None):
    if plural == None:
        plural = singular + 's'
    return "{} {}".format(number, singular if number == 1 else plural)

print (pl(1, 'child', 'children')) # 1 adult
print (pl(2, 'child', 'children')) # 2 children
print (pl(1, 'adult', 'adults')) # 1 adult
print (pl(2, 'adult')) # 2 adults
print (pl(1, 'adult')) # 1 adult
print (pl(5, 'adult', 'adults')) # 5 adults
```

Comment: Do I edit the coding under the function? or should I add the if statement into other coding where I am displaying the sentence?

Comment: You add function somewhere above and later you can use it in your print statement, it return string composed of number with proper form: `print("choice for " + pl(noAdult, 'adult') + " and " + pl(noChild, 'child', 'children') + ". Enjoy!")`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the plural and singular to be more general you may consider to use inflect, [an python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect)

Then the conversion will looks like this:

```
import inflect

conversion_engine = inflect.engine()

def main():

    for count in range(4):
        print format_plural_singular("child",count)
        print format_plural_singular("adult",count)
        print

def format_plural_singular(noun,quantity):
    return conversion_engine.plural_noun(noun,quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pluralize(singular, plural):
    def fn(num):
        return "{} {}".format(num, singular if num==1 else plural)
    return fn

children = pluralize("child",  "children")
adults   = pluralize("adult",  "adults")
seniors  = pluralize("senior", "seniors")
```

then

```
children(0)    # =>  "0 children"
children(1)    # =>  "1 child"
children(2)    # =>  "2 children"
```

and

```
def participants(num_seniors, num_adults, num_children):
    items = [
        (num_seniors,  seniors),
        (num_adults,   adults),
        (num_children, children)
    ]
    items = [fn(n) for n,fn in items if n > 0]

    # join last pair of items with "and"
    items[-2:] = [" and ".join(items[-2:])]
    # join all preceding items with ","
    return ", ".join(items)

participants(1, 2, 1)  # => "1 senior, 2 adults and 1 child"
participants(0, 1, 4)  # => "1 adult and 4 children"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a very basic solution that followed a simple rule to add *s* if the count is more than 1. You can use Python's f-string form to do a simple inline if-statement in the f-string.

```
print(f"That is {formatCurrency(rare)} for rare choice for {noAdult} 
        adult{'s' if noAdult != 1 else ''} and {noChild}
        child{'ren' if noChild != 1 else ''}. Enjoy!"
)
```